# Group conversations of 2 speakers from timestamps into a dataframe: Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, azure, timestamp

I have the conversation between two speakers "A" and "B" with their timestamps. Successive A  until B makes a Question and the trailing Bs until an A makes the answer for the question. I want to make a Question- Answer pair, where A asks the question and B answers( this will be one row of the dataframe)

Note: A word is spoken for each timestamp
This is what the dataset looks like:

| Index | Word | Offset | Speaker |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 85 | the | 433900000 | A |
| 86 | client | 439300000 | A |
| 87 | requirement | 443600000 | A |
| 88 | of | 449800000 | A |
| 89 | migrating | 451400000 | A |
| 90 | to | 456800000 | A |
| 91 | home | 457400000 | B |
| 92 | the | 462800000 | A |
| 93 | snowflake | 463700000 | A |
| 94 | karma | 509800000 | B |

I have just started learning python, so please don't be too harsh.
This is my code:

filename="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Sn1RHvhdHIrCuO_Yebohyk17Ow0IkBej/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=105987366122617111891&rtpof=true&sd=true"

```
`import pandas as pd
 df2=pd.read_excel(filename="")
 df3=pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(100), columns=["Question","Answer"])
 a=[]
 j=0
 for i in range(len(df2)):
     while(df2["Speaker"][i]=="A"):
        a.append(df2["Word"][i])
 df3["Question"][j]=a
 a.clear()
     else:
        a.append(df2["Word"][i])
 df3["Answer"][j]=a
 a.clear()
 j=j+1`
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ;)
Please add a portion of the data as a code snippet so everyone can copy and paste it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you simply mark each trail related to a distinct speaker a `groupby` operation without sorting would deliver the result.

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
df = pd.read_excel('dataset.xlsx')
string_groups = sum([['%s_%s' % (i,n) for i in g] for n,(k,g) in enumerate(itertools.groupby(df.Speaker))],[])
df['Sector'] = string_groups
print(df.groupby('Sector', sort=False).agg({'Word': ' '.join}))
```

output:

```
                                                     Word
Sector                                                   
A_0     the problem customer problem why are they migr...
B_1                                                  yeah
A_2     so what exactly is the client requirement of m...
B_3                                                  home
A_4                                         the snowflake
B_5                             karma city park now it is
```